# How to fix "Bad Request","status":400"

Tags: twitch, twitch-api

I try to get twitch api with following website https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ chennal name ,but nothing happened and get error 
{"error":"Bad Request","status":400,"message":"No client id specified"}

I expect to get viewers count and follower count

Comment: Perhaps include your client ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's necessary to include your client ID with the request. For example:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json' \
    -H 'Client-ID: uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2' \
    -X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/44322889'
```

[See here for details](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/#step-1-setup) on setting up your client ID.

Comment: Thank you for answer but how can i get it with channel name