# How to get JSON response Twitch

Tags: twitch, twitch-api

I try to get JSON response from https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users?login=CHANNEL NAME BUT

```
{"error":"Bad Request","status":400,"message":"No client id specified"}
```

I expect to get:

```
{
  "_id": "44322889",
  "bio": "Just a gamer playing games and chatting. :)",
  "created_at": "2013-06-03T19:12:02.580593Z",
  "display_name": "dallas",
  "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/dallas-profile_image-1a2c906ee2c35f12-300x300.png",
  "name": "dallas",
  "type": "staff",
  "updated_at": "2017-02-09T16:32:06.784398Z"
}
```

Comment: You are already getting a JSON response. Also the error is JSON formated. Please select a proper matching Topic. The error it self is a copy from your other question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Bad Request","status":400"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893620/how-to-fix-bad-request-status400)

Comment: I found solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fix formatting before posting next time, please.

Second of all, take a look at this:
https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/#getting-a-client-id